# Melhorar qualidade da imagem com thumbnail

Tags: php

Colegas

Estou ajustando um sistema do qual algumas imagens já existiam em um determinado diretório, não foi feito o tratamento de thumbnail nos cadastros e as imagens estavam demorando um pouco para abrir, pois estão usando o thumbnail do bootstrap.

```
<img src=\"produtos/".$foto."\" data-imagezoom=\"true\" class=\"img-responsive thumb-image\">
```

Para diminuir o impacto, criei um método onde diminuo a imagem com php:

```
public function gerarThumb($foto){

        list($largura,$altura) = getimagesize($foto);

        $novaLargura = 300;
        $novaAltura = 300;

        $miniatura = imagecreatetruecolor($novaLargura, $novaAltura);
        $imagem = imagecreatefromjpeg($foto);
        imagecopyresampled($miniatura, $imagem, 0, 0, 0, 0, $novaLargura, 
        $novaAltura, $largura, $altura);
        imagejpeg($miniatura,$foto,50); // Já coloquei 100 e não funcionou
        return $foto;
}
```

Consegui diminuir a imagem, porém a qualidade está muito ruim. Vejam uma das fotos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As fotos são jpg e png. Como eu poderia melhorar a qualidade das imagens?

Comment: Parece que você está sobrescrevendo a imagem original com o thumb. Tentativas seguintes só vão gerar novos thumbs piorados.

Comment: Olá bfaveretto. Como eu poderia corrigir isso?

Comment: A `$foto` que a função recebe é o caminho da imagem original? Se for, veja que o `imagejpeg( $miniatura, $foto, 50 );` recebe a `$foto` e salva por cima dela. Se você não tiver cópia dessa foto original, acho que ela já era. Para não sobrescrever, passe um novo caminho para o thumb. E use qualidade mais alta, 90 ou mais.

Comment: Obrigado bfavaretto. Estarei alterando o código.